# How to replace reflection image?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, shaders

How would I replace this cube's reflection

[image: shiny]

With something like this?

[image: material]

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this for your World (Environment) Shader - it's just 2 Noise Textures with the detail turned down, scaled slightly differently and subtracted from each other. I also added ColorRamps to help "define" the shapes a bit better:

[image: Color1]

If you want the background to appear plain, while still providing lighting and reflections, mix your patterned background with a plain background using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *Light Path* node as a mix factor. I also added another ColorRamp because the colors looked a bit blurred and indistinct on the reflections. I also ended up inverting the image (by way of the ColorRamp) because it looked a bit closer to your reference image, but I don't think it really matters that much.

[image: Color2]

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to set the texture as a normal map on the cuboid?